# jtvlc didn't generate the vlc.sdp file

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, streaming

Hi I'm trying to stream the video from my computer to justin.tv but I don't know what is the exactly the problem I never success to get the `vlc.sdp` file at where I located in the xxx.bat file

here is my code that I included in the file

Operation System is Windows XP

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -vvv -I rc "C:\playlist\karate-monkey.avi" --sout="#transcode{venc=x264{keyint=60,idrint=2},vcodec=h264,vb=300,scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=32,channels=2,samplerate=22050}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=1234,sdp=file://C:\playlist\vlc.sdp}"
```

the only thing I see in the log is that

```
main playlist debug: nothing to play
```

and its also said that not found the vlc.sdp file

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to answer my question I just got this work by simply add one more slash at the `file://` so it should be like this

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -vvv -I rc "C:\playlist\karate-monkey.avi" --sout="#transcode{venc=x264{keyint=60,idrint=2},vcodec=h264,vb=300,scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=32,channels=2,samplerate=22050}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=1234,sdp=file:///C:\playlist\vlc.sdp}"
```